# Responsive Layouts For Android App.

Tags: android-layout

I have an app which is using relative layout below is the xml code for view.

problem is it is showing different sizes on different devices

How can I achieve responsive lay`enter code here`out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="From Date"
           >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/               
            android:id="@+id/editText1""
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/editText1               

            android:text="Office Wise"
            android:width="150px" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if this is even a real question? Your single layout will display differently if the devices you are using are different sizes.

There is plenty of documentation on screen sizes etc:
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/design/style/devices-displays.html

One or all of these will help you

Comment: Thanks let go through it and revert.